# Leading question on 2013 survey?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I found this question on the 2013 survey a little leading:

> ### How often are you contacted by recruiters?
>
> ( ) An insane amount
> ( ) A slightly less than insane amount
> ( ) Never

There's no way to say "an appropriate amount" or "once in a while, but less than I'd like" or something like that. I suspect that very few people would ever actually check those boxes if they were there, but why bother even asking the question if you're not open to the possibility of being surprised? Is it just there for comic relief?

**Edit**: I wanted to clarify my objection a little more. I know that a big part of the goal for Careers 2.0 is to present a better alternative to the way everyone else is doing recruiting/hiring. The core assumption is "developers hate the way it works now, our way is better". (FWIW, I agree.) Asking this question in this way effectively restricts users to only answering in a way that confirms your hypothesis.

It's kind of like that question Stephen Colbert often asks his guests: "George W. Bush: great president or greatest president?"

Comment: I interpreted it as yes/no. ;)

Comment: Just like multiple choice in school, I selected the "best" answer... which was "A slightly less than insane amount" since I couldn't say "An insane amount" nor could I say "Never".

Comment: ( ) In Soviet Russia, you contact recruiters!